# Newton-Raphson's method user input and numerical output problems

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, sympy, newtons-method

I've been trying to create a script that allows the user to input an equation and returned the root of that equation. However I've ran into an issue and I've noticed that on running the program it takes the input and runs it through the loop but it doesn't assign the variables to the functions.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.lines as lines
from matplotlib import style
from scipy.misc import derivative
import sympy as sp

symx = sp.Symbol('x')

def f(symx):
    tmp = sp.sympify(input("Input your function here: "))
    return tmp;

def fprime(symx):
    tmp = sp.diff(f(symx))
    return tmp;

def newtons_method(f, fprime, symx):   
    guess = int(input("Enter an initial guess: ")) # Convert to an int immediately.
    for i in range(1,10):
        nextGuess = guess - f(guess)/fprime(guess)
        print(nextGuess)
        guess = nextGuess

def main():
    newtons_method(f, fprime, symx)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This is what the script outputs;

```
Enter an initial guess: 2
Input your function here: 2*x**3 + 2*x**2
Input your function here: 2*x**3 + 2*x**2
2 - (2*x**3 + 2*x**2)/(6*x**2 + 4*x)
Input your function here: 2*x**3 + 2*x**2 
Input your function here: 2*x**3 + 2*x**2 
2 - 2*(2*x**3 + 2*x**2)/(6*x**2 + 4*x)
```

Any help on improving is greatly appreciated, but could you also explain in depth any mistakes and improvements thank you.

Comment: Why do you have ask for Input for the function inside the `f(symx)`, surely you would want to ask for the function before you ask them to make a guess?

Comment: Yeah, thats way more logical. I guess I wasn't really thinking about it because it wasn't my main issue but I've changed it and its solved the looping problem, but I'm still not able to achieve a analytical solution to the root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not call the `input` function at any time, just in the initial moment, besides it is not necessary to pass the names of the functions.

```
import sympy as sp

x = sp.symbols('x')

def f(symx):
    tmp = sp.sympify(symx)
    return tmp

def fprime(symx):
    tmp = sp.diff(f(symx))
    return tmp;

def newtons_method():   
    guess = sp.sympify(float(input("Enter an initial guess: "))) # Convert to an int immediately.
    symx = input("Input your function here: ")
    div = f(symx)/fprime(symx)

    for i in range(1, 10):
        print(guess.evalf())
        nextGuess = guess - div.subs(x, guess)
        guess = nextGuess


def main():
    newtons_method()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Test:

```
Enter an initial guess: 2
Input your function here: 2*x**3 + 2*x**2
2.00000000000000
1.25000000000000
0.760869565217391
0.448024718605164
0.254024574811046
0.138693453631666
0.0733275286119194
0.0378747932767810
0.0192767426403216

Enter an initial guess: 2
Input your function here: x**2-2
2.00000000000000
1.50000000000000
1.41666666666667
1.41421568627451
1.41421356237469
1.41421356237310
1.41421356237309
1.41421356237310
1.41421356237309
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, is there a way I can plot this function?

Comment: Do you want to plot `2*x**3+2*x** 2`?

Comment: I'm looking to plot the inputted function, not necessarily that function

Comment: in your case: `sp.plotting.plot(f(symx))`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the sympy module, so I used `.replace` to replace the `x` with the guess and I used `eval()` to calculate the result

**These are the functions I've changed:**

```
def f(value):
    eq1 = eq.replace("x", str(value))
    tmp = eval(eq1) # sympy uses eval anyway
    return tmp;

def fprime(value):
    eq2 = str(sp.diff(eq).replace("x", str(value)))
    tmp = eval(eq2) 
    return tmp;

def newtons_method(f, fprime, symx):
    global eq
    eq = input("Input your function here: ") # ask for function first :)
    guess = int(input("Enter an initial guess: ")) # Convert to an int immediately.
    for i in range(1,10):
        nextGuess = guess - f(guess)/fprime(guess)
        print(nextGuess)
        guess = nextGuess
```

**This is the output given:**

```
>>> 
Input your function here: x**2 - 16
Enter an initial guess: 3
4.166666666666667
4.003333333333333
4.000001387732445
4.000000000000241
4.0
4.0
4.0
4.0
4.0
>>>
```

Hope this helps you :)